# How to bind items in a ListView Adapter to a Service?

Tags: android, service, adapter

I'm writing a radio application, in which the user will be able to download some shows.

When the user click on a download button on the audio player, the show is added to the DB as a `SavedShow`.

The user can see the state of the `SavedShow` instances in a `SavedShowsFragment`, which shows a `ListView` with the list of the saved shows.

In each row of the `ListView` is the title of the saved show, its state (`NOT_STARTED/DOWNLOADING/PAUSED/DOWNLOADED/ERROR`), a `ProgressBar` and a `Button` to pause the download, resume it or play the file if it's downloaded.

Now I don't know how to bind each item of the list to my `DownloadService` nor how to implement listeners from `DownloadService` in the adapter.

Basically, I would like for each row to:

- get the progress from the `DownloadTask.onProgressUpdate` of my `DownloadService`
- be notified by the `DownloadService` when a download is finished or if there is an error
- call methods from `DownloadService` (e.g. pause the download when clicking the button if the file is downloading)

Anybody could help?

**SavedShowsFragment**

```
public class SavedShowsFragment extends Fragment {

    private DownloadService mDownloadService;
    private boolean mBoundToDownloadService = false;

    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.saved_show_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void setSavedShowList(){

        mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);   

        SavedShowAdapter adapter = new SavedShowAdapter(getActivity(), MyApplication.dbHelper.getSavedShowList());
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // start services

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DownloadService.class);
        getActivity().startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {         
        super.onResume();

        setSavedShowList();

        // bind service

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StreamService.class);
        getActivity().bindService(intent, mDownloadServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        // unbind service

        if (mBoundToDownloadService) {
            getActivity().unbindService(mDownloadServiceConnection);
        }

        super.onPause();
    }   

    private ServiceConnection mDownloadServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {          

            /*
             * Get service instance
             */

            DownloadServiceBinder binder = (DownloadServiceBinder) service;
            mDownloadService = binder.getService();         
            mBoundToDownloadService = true;

            /*
             * Start download for NOT_STARTED saved show
             */

            for(SavedShow savedShow : MyRadioApplication.dbHelper.getSavedShowList()){

                if(savedShow.getState()==SavedShow.State.NOT_STARTED){
                    mDownloadService.downLoadFile(savedShow.getId());
                }           
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBoundToDownloadService = false;
        }
    };  

}
```

**SavedShowAdapter**

```
public class SavedShowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SavedShow> { 

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title, status;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        Button downloadStateBtn;
    }


    public SavedShowAdapter(Context context, List<SavedShow> saved_show_list) {
        super(context, 0, saved_show_list);     
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {

            v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.podcast_list_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.status = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.status);
            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            holder.downloadStateBtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_download_state);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.downloadStateBtn.setTag(position);

        // TODO set button state according to item state

        holder.downloadStateBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int position = (Integer) v.getTag();

                    // TODO call DownloadService method (download or pause) according to the state
            }
        });

        //holder.title.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());

        // do a publish progress listener for progress bar

        return v;
    }
}
```

**DownloadService**

```
public class DownloadService extends Service {

    private static final int MAX_DOWNLOAD_TASKS = 10;

    private final IBinder mBinder = new DownloadServiceBinder();

    private class MaxDownloadsException extends Exception
    {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6859017750734917253L;

        public MaxDownloadsException()
        {
            super(getResources().getString(R.string.max_downloads));
        }
    }

    private List<DownloadTask> mTaskList= new ArrayList<DownloadTask>();

    private void addTaskToList(DownloadTask task) throws MaxDownloadsException {

        if(mTaskList.size() < MAX_DOWNLOAD_TASKS+1){
            mTaskList.add(task);
        }
        else{
            throw new MaxDownloadsException(); 
        }
    }

    private void removeTaskToList(DownloadTask task) {

        mTaskList.remove(task);

        // if no more tasks, stop service

        if(mTaskList.size() == 0){
            stopSelf();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    /*
     * Binding-related methods
     */

    public class DownloadServiceBinder extends Binder {
        DownloadService getService() {
            return DownloadService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void downLoadFile(long savedShowId){

        new DownloadTask().execute(savedShowId);

    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Integer, Void> {

        private SavedShow savedShow;

        private int contentLength;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Long... params) {

            savedShow = MyApplication.dbHelper.getSavedShow(params[0]);

            int contentLength;

            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedInputStream in = null;

            try {               

                URL url = new URL(savedShow.getUrl());  

                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                long fileLength = new File(getFilesDir(), savedShow.getFilename()).length();

                FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(savedShow.getFilename(), MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND);

                int downloaded = 0;             
                contentLength = connection.getContentLength();

                // If there is already a file with that filename,
                // add 'Range' property in header                       

                if(fileLength != 0){
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + fileLength + "-");
                }       

                in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

                //BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream, 1024);

                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                int x = 0;

                while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, x);
                    downloaded += x;
                    publishProgress((int) (downloaded));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {               
                MyApplication.dbHelper.updateSavedShowError(savedShow.getId(), e.toString());

            }
            finally{
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(connection != null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return null;        

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            // How can I pass values to SavedShowAdapter's items?
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void nothing) {
            super.onPostExecute(nothing);

            // TODO remove task

            // How can I notify SavedShowAdapter's items?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did:

- to call `DownloadService` methods from the `SavedShowAdapter`, I passed the `Service` bound to the `SavedShowFragment` to the `SavedShowAdapter`.
- to get `DownloadService` listeners in the `Adapter`, I set some `BroadcastReceiver` in the `SavedShowFragment`, which then call `SavedShowAdapter`'s method that modify the data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're already binding to the service. You can inherit the default binder, and implement any methods you like on it, or create a messenger and send messages back and fourth. Both methods are explored in the API Guides, be sure to read through it and fully understand the advantages and disadvantages of each method:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: `SavedShowFragment` is bound to the service, not `SavedShowAdapter`. For instance how can I get the progress in my adapter's item from the service?

Comment: In the service, extend the binder, add a method to get the progress, create a local instance of it,  return that instance of the extended binder in onBind(). In the binder, cast it back to the extended class, call the method when needed. Again, please read the linked document.